# Unable to delete tomcat server from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am unable to delete the previous existing server from the eclipse.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First option:

- To remove an eclipse server you need to right-click on the server you want to remove and then click "Delete".

Second option:

- Select the server you want to remove and press the "Delete" button on the keyboard.

I hope I've helped.